# What's up with warnings about runtime not being a 'perfect match' to 'RequiredExecutionEnvironment'?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi

There is this warning I regularly encounter when working with Java/Eclipse/Maven/OSGi:

`The JRE container on the classpath is not a perfect match to the 'JavaSE-1.6' execution environment`

I am on a Java 7 JDK. Most project require (rightly so I think) a lower version than that. For example they will require JavaSE-1.6 or JavaSE-1.5. So in their `MANIFEST.MF`, these projects will have an entry that looks like this (sample taken from a bundle project of mine):

`Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6`

This will give me the mentioned warning. Now, I know of two possible ways to 'solve' this warning:

1. Replace the current runtime environment for the project with a Java 6 runtime
2. Change the MANIFEST entry to `JavaSE-1.7`

Both 'solutions' seem completely ludicrous to me. My project does not require JavaSE-1.7. It runs perfectly fine on JavaSE-1.6. Requiring all users of the bundle to have at least Java 7, just because the developer was on Java 7 and did not like the warning seems to me to be the opposite of what you would want. On the other hand, requiring me as a developer to have all versions of Java installed that are listed as required execution environment on projects I work with seems to be almost just as ludicrous. All these projects run perfectly fine on Java 7 so why would I need to have many of them?

Am I completely missing something (in which case I am [not](http://www.mymiller.name/wordpress/programming/eclipse-programming/jre-container-on-the-classpath-is-not-a-perfect-match) [the](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t113874.html) [only](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=162762) [one](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t106393.html)), or is this warning really stupid as it is actively promoting developers to set a much higher required execution environment for their projects as would be strictly needed?? Any insight (and hopefully a third way to get rid of this warning) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 'not a perfect match' is warning you that you might use something in the Java 7 runtime libraries which is not in the Java 6 libraries - so your code would not actually run on Java 6.

Comment: Yes I get that part... But I think it's silly reasoning. I will just test my project on Java 6 once in a while... Is there a way to get rid of this warning other than the two methods I mentioned?

Comment: You don't know that you project runs fine on Java 6 unless you actually compile regularly with Java 6. It's far too easy to use API introduced in Java 7. This is what the warning is telling you. If you are going to support Java 6, you will need to have it installed and defined in your workspace. You can still launch with Java 7.

Comment: Guess it's time for acceptance... I downloaded the Java 6 JDK.  :)  If you are willing to write a good answer for it I will accept it.

Comment: I can't even find these old JREs for Mac!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three possible ways to get rid of the warning:

1. Replace the current runtime environment for the project with a Java 6 runtime (recommended)
2. Change the MANIFEST entry to JavaSE-1.7
3. Change the build settings to ignore the warning

---

**Replace the current runtime environment for the project with a Java 6 runtime**

This is the recommended solution. What the warning is trying to say is that specifying a minimum required execution environment of Java 6, but then using a Java 7 environment during development is inherently risky as you could write some code that only works in Java 7 and you would not notice this until you deploy to a Java 6 environment and it breaks *(thanks to [greg-449](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) and [Konstantin Komissarchik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555576/konstantin-komissarchik) for mentioning this in the comments)*.

**Step 1**: Add a new Java 6 Runtime environment:

Window -> Preferences -> Java / Installed JREs -> button 'Add...'

[image: Eclipse preferences, Java/Installed JREs]

**Step 2**: Select the newly added JRE as runtime for the project

Poject -> Properties -> Java Build Path

[image: Eclipse Project properties, Java Build Path]

---

**Change the MANIFEST entry to JavaSE-1.7**

This solution is simple enough. The big downside is that you will be forcing all users of your project to upgrade their Java runtime to whichever version you are using. So it's not so good if you want to support older runtimes as well.

---

**Change the build settings to ignore the warning**

Just make Eclipse stop complaining. **WARNING**: Use with care. Ignoring the warning could make you miss breaking backwards compatibility with older VMs without noticing it.

Window -> Preferences -> Java / Compiler / Building (or the equivalent per-project page if it applies):

[image: Java Building preference page]

Comment: W00t w00t!! That looks like it's just what I was looking for. Not in the position to test it right now, but will try this out tonight.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very important problem and I agree with the previous solutions given, but this message is still delivered in the following recent context :

- Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developpers : Luna (SR1a-win32), the most recent download available in january 2015 for my Vista machine
- installed JRE : version 8 (update 1.8.0_25-b18).

I tried a thing I haven't done for a long time (maybe since the first time I used Eclipse) : trying the examples available on the Welcome page, an icon labelled "Samples - Try out the samples". I did it, a wizzard installed a lot of source code in one project, and I got the a red exclamation mark on the project root. Looking at the Problems view gave the solution : the entire project is defined for the old J2SE-1.4 JRE.

It seemed easy to change that in the Java Build Path window, by editing the JRE System Library of the project : I selected the Workspace default JRE (jre1.8.0_25) option.

And that's the point I got the message "The JRE container of the classpath is not a perfect match to the 'J2SE-1.4' execution environment". I decided to attempt to resolve this (trivial) problem, to get a clean starting point to my investigation in the examples code. It was not so obvious.

Double-clicking on the error message in the Problems view takes you in the Manifest file of the project, on the line with the red mark :

```
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4
```

Trying to change the version 1.4 by 1.8 is not the solution, you get the message : "'J2SE-1.8' is not a valid Execution Environment".

Trying to remove the line is no more the solution, you get the message : 
"No required execution environment has been set".

After spending a little bit of time, the correct action I founded is simple : do the same thing with the manifest editor of Eclipse to get the correct name of the option : it is not J2SE-1.8 but JavaSE1.8

Here is the proc :

1. in the Overview pane of the manifest file in the editor view, in the Execution Environments scope, clic the Add... button and select JavaSE-1.8
2. Select J2SE1.4 and clic the Remove button.

That's it.